# Show density of the image of the function T

Tags: number-theory

I have to solve the following task:

Let be $\alpha = 0.1234567891011...$ the Champernowne number. We consider the function $T: [0,1) \rightarrow [0,1)$ with $T(x) := \{ 10x \}$ while $\{x\} = x - \lfloor x \rfloor$. Now I have to show that the sequence $(T^k(\alpha))_{k\geq 0}$
is a dense set in $[0,1)$.

I tried to use the following defintion to show the result:

$ \forall x \in [0,1) \;\; \forall \epsilon>0 \;\; \exists k_0 \in \mathbb{N}: \; \vert x - T^{k_0}(\alpha) \vert < \epsilon $

My problem is to find the right $k_0$ and I don't know how to estimate the expression $\vert x - T^{k_0}(\alpha) \vert$

Can someone help me please?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's a proof, or a sketch, or hints, if you like.

Let $x$ be in $[0,1)$.  Pick $\epsilon<0$.

Now truncate the decimal expansion of $x$ to a number $y$ such that $x-y<\frac{1}{2}\epsilon$.

Then, if you can find a $k$ such that $|y-T^{k}(\alpha)| < \frac{1}{2}\epsilon$, you'll have it.

Now, $T^{k}(\alpha)$ is the number we get by moving the decimal point $k$ digits over in $\alpha$ and throwing away the integer portion.  Since $\alpha$ contains every finite sequence of digits, we can find a spot in $\alpha$ where the digits exactly agree with $y$'s followed by, say, $Z$ zeros.  That is, there exists a $k$ such that 
$$ |T^{k}(\alpha)-y| <10^{-Z}. $$ 
Since $Z$ can be chosen to be any positive integer, choose $Z$ so that
$10^{-Z}<\frac{1}{2}\epsilon$ and you have the result.